# May I add this package to my existing Java project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am beginning at Java GUI, so I ask you professional coders to be understading towards to my humble question.

So, I have been coding this small Java project. I came across a problem, which is to query a Json file. During my quest over the internet looking for an answer, I stumbled upon this project on github:

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Which proved to be the solution for my problem. Everything I need to be able to search for specific nodes on a json file is there, hard coded.

My beginner question: Is that possible to include this 'JsonPath' in my existing project? The IDE is Apache Netbeans 10.0 and the project is a Java SE application.

Thanks in advance!

I tried searching Services->Maven repository->Find...

I happened to find this package but I have no clue how to add the package. Also, I am not sure if its possible to add it to my project.

At first I thought doing something like "com.jayway.jsonpath" to my main class would solve my problem - But obvisouly it didn't, that's why I'm asking you guys for some guidance.

Comment: Did you try following the instructions from the GitHub page starting with "Maven users add this to your POM"? (Are you using Maven?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use a dependency management tool like [Gradle](https://gradle.org) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) *first*.  This gives you a place to put all of the third-party dependencies like this one in your project.  (Note: how to use or install either of those tools is outside of the scope of this question.)

Then, you just need the **Maven coordinates**.  Luckily the project [has those coordinates available](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/jar).

Comment: As Maven is already built in Netbeans I managed to solve my issue by learning how to use it properly. Thank you sir, you just did save my day =)